# What is the solution of android error : V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service?

Tags: android

I facing this error in android project. I trying to retrieve data from database (using php web service)  but logcat is showing- V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If you have found the solution, but I have faced a weird thing:

I like to program with OOP and I have put my code which executes login inside a separated Java Class (not in the Activity). So When I try to run the code, the `V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service` always appear.

When I remove this same code from my Java Class and insert it in the body of Activity and run the app, it works.

So, I think the problem is about the threads in separated between the Activity and my Class. I don't know if you use separated Java Classes too and I not found the resolution for this yet, but it's a good place to start.